# Correct usage of \bibliography command in arXiv submission

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, arxiv, bbl

I know that arXiv does not run BibTeX, and so one needs to submit both the `.tex` and the `.bbl` file. I am wondering about the correct way of using `\bibliographystyle` and `\bibliography` in the `.tex` file.

I have been experimenting a little, and it seems that `\bibliographystyle` is not needed. Also, writing `\bibliography{}` seems to work just as well as `\bibliography{foo}`; on the other hand, removing it does not seem to work.

So my question is, what is the correct usage of `\bibliographystyle` and `\bibliography` inside a `.tex` file that is submitted to `arXiv`?

Comment: Arxiv requires the `.bbl` file because they **never** runs `bibtex`. So basically you can replace `\bibliography{...}` with the entire contents of the `.bbl` file.

Comment: @daleif Thanks for your comment. I see, but what if I want to upload both the `.tex` and the `.bbl` file? Should `\bibliographystyle` and `\bibliography` be present in the `.tex` file? What should be their argument?

Comment: The system does not care that information is never used. `\bibliography` just inputs the `.bbl` and writes the names of the `.bib` file(s) to the `.aux` but arxiv never cares as it never runs `bibtex`.

Comment: @daleif By "that information" you mean the argument of `\bibliography`, right? Because if I comment out `\bibliography`, then the references are not processed correctly by arXiv. I agree that `\bibliographystyle` is not needed.

Comment: `\bibliography{...}` is (over simplified) `\writeToAux{...}\InputIfFileExists{\jobname.bbl}`

Comment: @daleif Got it, thanks for the help!